# How to show min validation error in angular forms?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
**Component.html**

<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="signUpForm">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="fullName" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="fullName.hasError('required')">
          User Name is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="fullName.hasError('minLength')">
          User Name must have at least 5 characters
        </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</form>

**Component.ts**

 signUpForm = this.fb.group({
    fullName: ['dd', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: ['ss', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
  }, { validator: passwordMatchValidator })

  /* Shorthands for form controls (used from within template) */
  get fullName() { return this.signUpForm.get('fullName'); }
  get email() { return this.signUpForm.get('email'); }
  get password() { return this.signUpForm.get('password'); }
  get confirmPassword() { return this.signUpForm.get('confirmPassword'); }
```

i want to show min validation error, iam getting the red border highlited but not displaying errormessages can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be 'minlength':

```
*ngIf="fullName.hasError('minlength')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check the code and working example:

> *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength"

In component.ts:

> password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]

For deeply check the proper code snippet link:

[Angular form validation](https://therichpost.com/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-working-example/)

Thank you